# Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:ed28f77472e9bdb07f669a8553f4bca07f63f397e9a2be39433d14aef1d7f037
   - SHA1:0096e66eb8e785b7f489de7a256b754fc1369590 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8310d01d8374b2dd121b71487e87cdb9 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:2643080 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:80e8ff5cd12b3ad0c260e91efa4cfe7c753a9159aeb5ad68e37b75000112e8e2
   - SHA1:30e30a763904ff256c5a88b655d217ac8e69ff54 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5e1f1e2868f221aebfdb1cb06b703253 [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:1020 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 21:32:53 +0000
Fetched 140 MB in 2min 42s (861 kB/s)                                          
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/pool/non-free/w/windows-binaries/windows-binaries_0.5-0kali1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:ed28f77472e9bdb07f669a8553f4bca07f63f397e9a2be39433d14aef1d7f037
    - SHA1:0096e66eb8e785b7f489de7a256b754fc1369590 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8310d01d8374b2dd121b71487e87cdb9 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:2643080 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:80e8ff5cd12b3ad0c260e91efa4cfe7c753a9159aeb5ad68e37b75000112e8e2
    - SHA1:30e30a763904ff256c5a88b655d217ac8e69ff54 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5e1f1e2868f221aebfdb1cb06b703253 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:1020 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 21:32:53 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: and this source.list :                                                                                      deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib:

Comment: I need to help , please

Comment: Please explain what happened when you followed the advice in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `apt-get update` and make sure it doesn't report error.